# Amp is receiving radio signal?

Tags: keyboard, radio

My amp is playing a lot of radio stations at the same time.

The amp model is an Ibanez IBZ10Z, and it's plugged into my keyboard.

Comment: What is the model number of the amp and what do you currently have plugged into it?

Comment: Does this relate to recording or live sound? Or is this a home audio system?

Comment: It's IBZ10Z and it's plugged into my keyboard. @friend of george

Comment: If anyone still visits this thread, I'm having this same issue.. It only happens when the overdrive is on, and it only happens with this certain keyboard plugged into it.. I need both of these things to acheive the specific sound I'm seeking. Does anybody know the solution w this details added? Thanks

Comment: It also happens w any cable ive tried (all guitar cables, short and long) and with multiple outlets on separate lines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the equipment is grounded, this could be a [ground loop](http://www.epanorama.net/documents/groundloop/basics.html). (If you're using AC power and three-prong plugs, the third prong is the ground.) Try plugging the amp into a different outlet, one that's on a different circuit. They make ground loop isolators, but I don't know if they work or not; it might be worth investigating.

(I've used three-to-two-prong adapters to get rid of ground loop problems in a pinch, but I don't recommend it as more than a temporary solution. As per Owen's comments, it's quite dangerous to do this.)

Comment: A word of caution, as noted above, removing the earth on any device with an earth pin is inviting danger. If it was a guitar amp for example, as the person holding the guitar, and thus touching the strings you become the earth.

Comment: @Owen - I agree, not something to be done with regularity or with delicate equipment. Could this cause a hazard if guitars aren't involved?

Comment: It would depend on the nature of the device. By removing the ground, any charge that would normally pass through the ground (such as an electrical fault), will now need to find a new exit. If you are touching any part of the device which could be connected to the ground (such as the chassis, or metal enclosure), then you will become the ground. Touching the strings on an electrical guitar (for an unearthed amp), or holding a microphone (for an unearthed mixer) could result in some fatal earthing. Try a Ground Loop Isolater instead.

Comment: @Owen - Do ground loop isolators take care of the problem similarly?

Comment: From my experience, sometimes it does. I believe it should be inline on the signal line, though I have only ever tried this on a dc player, turntable. Not on an instrument. The theory is similar I think, but I'm not 100%.

Answer (score 2):

This could be a potential answer to you question.

I was told one of the major reasons for balanced cables (note most guitar cables are unbalanced), is to prevent interference. Most notable is that of radio transmissions being picked up. The length of the cable relates to the frequency it will pickup, though your amp, or pickups could also pick up the signal.

Proper shielding, and shorter cables should solve the issue.

If your keyboard and amp can take a balanced cable investigate how to achieve this, as it should solve your issues.

[Other examples of amps picking up radio stations](http://www.ultimate-guitar.com/forum/showthread.php?t=664950)

Answer (score 1):

If the extra noise is happening when you are playing the keyboard, make sure the Overdrive is turned off.  Also, try plugging your guitar into the amp and see if it does the same thing.

If the extra noise is happening when you are not playing the keyboard, unplug the keyboard and see if it stops.  Also, try adjusting all the knobs to see if anything changes.

If the noise is more like a buzzing sound, try @Neil Fein's suggestion about ground loops.